# java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: java, mysql, symfony, jdbc

I have installed lampp with Tomcat on my computer as I need them for a project. I've used Symfony to create one part of the application. I've created another application but this time using Tomcat. The two applications use the same database however the one running Tomcat is not able to connect.

When I run both projects from my computer then everything works; however when I run them on my server only the Symfony application is able to access the database.

I get the following exception when running through Tomcat

```
 java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Does anyone know what the issue is here?

**symfony database connection**

```
database_driver: pdo_mysql
database_host: 127.0.0.1
database_port: null
database_name: blablablabla
database_user: root
database_password: null
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
mailer_user: null
mailer_password: null
locale: en
secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

**tomcat project  connection**

```
  package com.beans;
public class Bean_BaseDeDonnee:


private String nom =jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/blablablabla;
```

**class1 : Bean_BaseDeDonnee.java ** i *I initialize the connection in this class*

**end class1**

**class2**   *i do all the import necessary here*

```
       try
                    {

                       Class.forName( "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" );
                        request.setAttribute( "texte", "le driver a été trouvé dans le classpath ! <br/>");
                    }

                       catch ( ClassNotFoundException e ) 
                    {
                     request.setAttribute( "texte", "Erreur lors du chargement : le driver n'a pas été trouvé dans le classpath ! <br/>");
                    }


                           Bean_BaseDeDonnee bd = new Bean_BaseDeDonnee();


                            /* Connexion à la base de données */
                            String url = bd.getNombd();
                            String utilisateur = "root";
                            String motDePasse = "";
                            Connection connexion = null;
                            Statement statement = null;
                            ResultSet resultat = null;
                            request.setAttribute( "texte", url);


                        try 
                        {
                        connexion = DriverManager.getConnection( url, utilisateur, motDePasse );

                        /* Création de l'objet gérant les requêtes */
                        statement = connexion.createStatement();
                        } 
                        catch (  SQLException e ) 
                        {
                        request.setAttribute( "texte", " n'a pas été trouvé dans le classpath ! <br/>");
                        }
```

Comment: Tomcat is only the delivery boy. The database is sending you that exception. And it is telling you: You are not allowed to login as root without a password. Probably you are in fact NOT connecting from the localhost so you need to grant access from within the database to connect outside of the localhost too.

Comment: if i am not allowed to login as root without password,why the connection of symfony don't fail???

Comment: Do you have mysql server installed locally, and setup to allow remote connections over TCP?

Comment: normally i have mysql server installed locally.i say in locally all is ok.the two application run very well.but in the dedicated Server i buy a few day,the application do with tomcat don't run

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your database is pointing to `localhost 127.0.0.1`. In the server config you should ensure that this points to the address of the machine running the DB server - unless the application and database runs on the same machine.